# Microsoft Excel 2010 Macro To Update Rows on Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some issues creating a macro >.>.. And would like to request some help, because remaking sheets and re-doing all the data is really a pain.. Essentially I have Sheet1 and Sheet2, Sheet1 Contains "NEW" Data, and Sheet2 the "OLD" Data.

Inside Sheet2 There are specific column headers for row 1, Such as: (B1)title, (E1)quantity. And in Sheet1 there are the Headers of; (A1)Title, (G1) Quantity.

Now my question is, can anyone create a working Macro that will scan through Sheet1 and Sheet2, Compare the Title Names, find the Common Titles.. And then simply UPDATE the quantity Column in Sheet2?

Sheet1 and Sheet2 Do NOT contain the same amount of Titles, but all the titles in Sheet2 should be found in Sheet1.. I just need it to Update the Quantity to the ones it finds in Sheet1.

Does that make sense? (not the entire row either)
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. This has been driving me mad. Thank you in advanced.

**Edit for Lance:**

```
Sheet1: 
  Title       id      Type    Paperid  Imageid  uuid     Quantity
  Batman5132                                              23

Sheet2: 
  category   title  description price   Quantity
  Batman5132                                  54
```

And I would want the macro, to take Sheet2's Titles and look through Sheet1's titles and find the exact same titles, and JUST update the Quantity cells (With the Columns listed above)

Comment: You'll need to define things better, like what you mean by Update.  Is the result, the total of both sheets, or just the total on one sheet?  Is it based on a count on the sheets, or the sum of the Quantity numbers?

Comment: @LanceRoberts Ok I will give an Example..

Sheet1:
Title        Quantity
Batman1523     42

Sheet2:
Title       Quantity
Batman1523     54

And I would want the macro, to take Sheet2's Titles and look through Sheet1's titles and find the exact same titles, and JUST update the Quantity cells (With the Columns listed in the above request)

Comment: OK, so what is the end result you want in the Sheet2 Quantity cell: 96 or 42?

Comment: @LanceRoberts 42, I want it to be the same as the quantitys found in Sheet1.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Do ya get it Lance?

Comment: it might help to write your question with spaces in between to emphasize what you are trying to do. like a Condition and what should happen right next to it. Its rather hard to read it all in one block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim rw2 As Range

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each rw2 In Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows
  If Not sh1.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(rw2.Cells(1, 2).Value,, xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    rw2.Cells(1, 5) = sh1.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(rw2.Cells(1, 2).Value,, xlValues, xlWhole).Offset(0, 6)
  End If
Next rw2
```

Comment: @LanceRoberts Lance, could you explain how this works just a bit please?

Comment: It picks worksheet 1 and then iterates through all the rows on worksheet 2.  For every row on worksheet 2, it checks to see if it finds the value on worksheet 1 (it won't handle dupes the way it's written).  If it finds the title value, then it assigns the quantity value from sheet 1 to sheet 2.

Comment: I would also include the "LookAt" parameter (as xlWhole in this case). Otherwise, the behaviour is to follow the last use of "Find", which may not be what you want...

Comment: @Lance and to be sure, so I dont mess it up when I try to run it..  what would I change to change the columns for title and quantity?

Comment: @Leaum, Personally, I'd code it to find out which columns the Title and Quantity are actually in.  What to change depends on how your actual spreadsheet is laid out.  I did this with an assumption that you only had the Title and Quantity columns, so UsedRange would cover everything.  If you have a lot more then you'll want to change most of the column references around, probably using letters, like Columns("B:B").

Comment: @Lance I do, I have quite a few columns actually.

Comment: @Leaum, then if the columns will never change, I'd specify them exactly (though it'd be better to calculate where they are everytime).

Comment: @LanceRoberts Here ya go lance, http://www.mediafire.com/?0676tqm7gthw63h  This is an example of my spread header... Do you think you could modify your macro to help me understand this? (I just started this stuff last week still wrapping my head around it)

Comment: @Lance The Columns will never change, they will stay in that position. And if they do change them for some reason, I can manage to change it in the macro I am sure once I see how you did it D:

Comment: @Lance I seem to be getting a "Run-time error '13': type mismatch" on "If Not sh1.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(rw2.Cells(1, 2).Value, xlWhole, xlValues) Is Nothing Then" Know why?

Comment: @Leaum, I put the xlWhole value in the wrong place, fixed now.

Comment: @Lance so it should run properly now? I'm on mobile via htc so can't really try now. Had to run a errand.

Answer (score 0):

If your data are decent and you are willing to execute a SQL statement from a Macro/Module Sub (Ref To ADO needed) or a script/program, the update could be done with a single

```
UPDATE [OldSheet$] AS O INNER JOIN [NewSheet$] AS N ON O.[Title] = N.[Title] SET O.[Quantity] = N.[Quantity]
```

Evidence:

```
SELECT * FROM [NewSheet$]
!Title  !Quantity!
!Title1 !      10!
!Title2 !      20!
!Title3 !      30!
!Title4 !      40!
!Title5 !      50!
!Title6 !      60!
!Title7 !      70!
!Title8 !      80!
!Title9 !      90!
!Title10!     100!

SELECT * FROM [OldSheet$]
!Title !Quantity!
!Title1!       1!
!Title3!       3!
!Title5!       5!
!Title7!       7!
!Title9!       9!

UPDATE [OldSheet$] AS O INNER JOIN [NewSheet$] AS N ON O.[Title] = N.[Title] SET O.[Quantity] = N.[Quantity]

SELECT * FROM [OldSheet$]
!Title !Quantity!
!Title1!      10!
!Title3!      30!
!Title5!      50!
!Title7!      70!
!Title9!      90!
```